# Regex rules in an array

Tags: php, regex

Maybe it can not be solved this issue as I want, but maybe you can help me guys.

I have a lot of malformed words in the name of my products.

Some of them has leading `(` and trailing `)` or maybe one of these, it is same for `/` and `"` signs.

What I do is that I am explode the name of the product by spaces, and examines these words.

So I want to replace them to nothing. But, a hard drive could be `40GB ATA 3.5" hard drive`. I need to process all the word, but I can not use the same method for `3.5"` as for `()` or `//` because this `3.5"` is valid.

So I only need to replace the quotes, when it is at the start of the string AND at end of the string.

```
$cases = [
    '(testone)',
    '(testtwo',
    'testthree)',
    '/otherone/',
    '/othertwo',
    'otherthree/',
    '"anotherone',
    'anothertwo"',
    '"anotherthree"',
];
$patterns = [
    '/^\(/',
    '/\)$/',
    '~^/~',
    '~/$~',
    //Here is what I can not imagine, how to add the rule for `"`
];
$result = preg_replace($patterns, '', $cases);
```

This is works well, but can it be done in one `regex_replace()`? If yes, somebody can help me out the pattern(s) for the quotes?

Result for quotes should be this:

```
'"anotherone', //no quote at end leave the leading
'anothertwo"', //no quote at start leave the trailin
'anotherthree', //there are quotes on start and end so remove them.
```

Comment: Does it mean you need 2 regexps - 1) for an initial `"` if the string ends with `"` - `'/^"(?=.*"$)/s'` and 2) for a trailing `"` if the first one was `"` (no way for the current approach)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Quotes only can be replaced, if the first character is a `"` and last character is `"` quote too, and shold be replaced only these 2 quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use another approach: rather than define an array of patterns, use one single alternation based regex:

```
preg_replace('~^[(/]|[/)]$|^"(.*)"$~s', '$1', $s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zL8tS4/1)

**Details**:

- `^[(/]` - a literal `(` or `/` at the start of the string
- `|` - or
- `[/)]$` - a literal `)` or `/` at the end of the string
- `|`  - or
- `^"(.*)"$` - a `"` at the start of the string, then any 0+ characters (due to `/s` option, the `.` matches a linebreak sequence, too) that are captured into Group 1, and `"` at the end of the string.

The replacement pattern is `$1` that is empty when the first 2 alternatives are matched, and contains Group 1 value if the 3rd alternative is matched.

Note: In case you need to replace until no match is found, use a `preg_match` with `preg_replace` together (see [demo](https://ideone.com/BG2B9J)):

```
$s = '"/some text/"';
$re = '~^[(/]|[/)]$|^"(.*)"$~s';
$tmp = '';
while (preg_match($re, $s) && $tmp != $s) {
    $tmp = $s;
    $s = preg_replace($re, '$1', $s);
}
echo $s;
```

Comment: It works great... Thank you! I am happy to undelete the post and accept your answer.

Comment: I not deleted it becuase I do not get answer, as you see my reputation, I am familiar SO a little bit. I deleted it, because when you asked, I thought, my question is not clear enough, and when I answered to your question, I did feel, it won't lead you closer to understand. Anyway, I have a question is about your solution, moment please.

Comment: Sorry, sure. If you check my history, you'll see I am not well-versed in question asking :( Just did not understand the reason. Sure, I will be glad to clarify any doubt.

Comment: Ok, I have no question after I read your answer again. It is brilliant how tricky you are with this `$1` thing. I never tought that it could be "hacked" like this way, that if you do not define a group, then $1 will be empty. Awesome, today I learned something new.

Comment: Actually, it is a good point: the `$1` is a backreference that is pre-populated with an empty string at each regex match. It does not work the same as pattern inline backreferences of `\<NUMBER>` notation (there is a difference between groups matching empty strings and optional groups that do not match). So, yes, it is safe to use `$1` here.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
preg_replace([[/(]?(.+)[/)]?|/\"(.+)\"/], '$1', $string)
```

Comment: Yes, but it can't be mixed with my `$pattersn` array, because in the other case I am replacing results to nothing, while you for `'$1'`

Comment: and you can use this site to test it out https://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html

Comment: Unoftunetly not good, `/` at the end remains, `)` at the end remains, `"anotherthree"` is untouched.